# Configuring Serilog throws collection modified exception

Tags: c#, serilog

I am creating .net 6 web api app and I am trying to configure serilog in it. Below is the snippet of the code. When executing, am getting collection was modified exception..

```
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Core;
using Serilog.Events;

var ihb = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
{
    webBuilder.ConfigureServices((context, collection) =>
    {
        collection.AddLogging(builder =>
        {
            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().
                MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(new LoggingLevelSwitch(LogEventLevel.Error))
                //  other configuration goes here
                .CreateLogger();
    
            webBuilder.UseSerilog(logger);
        });
    });
});

try
{
  var ih = ihb.Build();
  ih.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Could someone point out what the issue might be..

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, you can modify your code to configure Serilog outside the AddLogging method.

```
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Core;
using Serilog.Events;

var ihb = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.ConfigureServices((context, collection) =>
        {
            // Make a copy of the services collection
            var services = collection.BuildServiceProvider();

            // Retrieve the context object from the services collection
            var context = services.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();

            // Log configuration using the context object
            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(new LoggingLevelSwitch(LogEventLevel.Error))
                // other configuration using the context object
                .CreateLogger();

            // Use Serilog with the configured logger
            webBuilder.UseSerilog(logger);

            // Add logging services to the collection
            collection.AddLogging();
        });
    });

try
{
    var ih = ihb.Build();
    ih.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.. While creating the snippet, I missed a piece of code. The context object that is that is in ConfigureServices method is used in log configuration. so I cannot split this code. I have to have the log configuration inside the configureservice method.